# How to dynamically render any number of ng-template

Tags: angular

Maybe the title of the post is not so accurate. What im making is a tabs component, where clicking on a tab the view changes.
At the moment what i pass to the component is an array of tab identificators to render the tab buttons.

Now what i want is something like in the ng-content of the component pass it "n" number of templates or views like this:

```html
<my-tabs-component [tabs]="['tab1','tab2']">
    <ng-template [view]="'tab1'">
        Tab 1 content
    <ng-template/>
    <ng-template [view]="'tab2'">
        Tab 2 content
    <ng-template/>
</my-tabs-component>
```

Obviously that syntax is probably incorrect, i read something about templateOutlet but i cant reach the correct aproach.

Answer me with a link to docs, the solution... Any help is welcome.

Comment: why are you writing tabs? use a component lib.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can understand, you'll have to handle the tab switching logic(decide which tab is displayed) in the **parent** component. That is, the parent of `my-tabs-component`.

I think there are multiple ways to go about this, it depends on how complex your logic is.

These are the cases that come to mind:

#### Every tab is a component

If you have a small number of tabs(which I doubt), you can use [`ngComponentOutlet`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet) along with [`ng-container`](https://alligator.io/angular/ng-container-element/).

If you don't, you'll have to step into the low-level side of working with dynamic components. You can leverage the power of **embedded views** and **host views**.

An **embedded view** is created by an `ng-template` and it is called this way because it cannot display anything on its own, it must be attached to a **view container**.

A **host view** is a component that you will create **imperatively**. Still, you'll have to attach it to some other element, and the most convenient way is to use a **view container**.

You can read more about **embedded views** and **host views** [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/working-with-dom-in-angular-unexpected-consequences-and-optimization-techniques-682ac09f6866).

IMO, the must suitable candidate for a **view container** is an `ng-container`, which you can query for in your component class and gain access to the [`ViewContainerRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef) API.

I would encourage to try this approach because it offers you a way to preserve the tab states when switching between them, which means when you go from `TabA` to `TAbB` after adding some data to `TabA` and then going back to `TabA`, it could still have what you added before.

This can be achieved by using `ViewContainerRef.detach()` and `ViewContainerRef.insert()`.

Roughly, this could be an implementation:

```html
<my-tabs-component [tabs]="['tab1','tab2']">
 <ng-container #vcr></ng-container>
</my-tabs-component>
```

```js
@Component({})
export class ParentComp {
 @ViewChild('vcr', { static: true, read: ViewContainerRef })
 private vcr: ViewContainerRef;
 private prevLoadedTabName = 'tab1';
 private compMap = new Map<string, ComponentRef<any>>();
 private tabsFactories = { /* ... You components here */ };

 loadTab (tabName) {
  this.compMap.set(this.prevLoadedTabName, this.vcr.detach());

  this.prevLoadedTabName = tabName;

  if (this.compMap.has(tabName)) {
    this.compMap.insert(this.compMap.get(tabName));

    return;
   }

  this.vcr.createComponent(this.tabsFactories[tabName]);
 }
}
```

#### Every tab is an `ng-template`

It is similar to the aforementioned case. Instead of `ngComponentOutlet`, you can use `ngTemplateOutlet`.

If you have multiple `ng-template`s, you can still use an `ng-container` as above, except that you would now want to use the `ViewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView()` along with `ViewContainerRef.remove()` / `ViewContainerRef.clear()`.

In order to get the `ng-template`s from the view, you can use `@ViewChildren(TemplateRef, { read: TemplateRef<any> }) templates: QueryList<TemplateRef<any>>` and `vcr.createEmbeddedView(templates.toArray()[idx])`;

I might have missed some details, but I hope I could share my thoughts on this in a precise way.